# Suitescript saved search without duplicates

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Hi I am in need of a saved search that does not return duplicate Submarket Labels. Reason is because this search returns like 24000 entries, but there are only like 10 submarket labels. I just need to pull what those individual labels are as strings (no duplicates) because i am comparing it to the submarket of the current ama.

```
var ama_search = search.create({
  type: 'customrecord_uc_ama',
  filters: [{
    name: 'isinactive',
    operator: search.Operator.IS,
    values: false,
  }],
  columns: ['custrecord_uc_submarketlabel']
});

//what i want to do
var all_submarketlabels = []

ama_search.run().each(function(result){
  if (result.custrecord_uc_submarketlabel not in all_submarketlabels) {
    all_submarketlabels.push(result.custrecord_uc_submarketlabel)
  }
}))
```

and all_submarketlabels would hold... all of the submarket labels ex: ['New York','Westchester','Los Angeles'] etc. and it would return TRUE if my AMA's submarket  was 'New York'

How can this be done ?

Once again, my current search returns 24k+ entries and maximum is 4000, so how can i make a lesser amount of yielded results ?

Putting it simply, I want a saved search on all AMA's so that i can get all possible values of Submarket Label and put it into an array. i would then compare my ama's submarket label to see if it is inside said array

THANKS !

Answer (score 2):

Use a GROUP summary on your `custrecord_uc_submarketlabel` Column.